# memory leak caused by Ehcache without expiration

Tags: java, ehcache

Ehcache version : 2.10.2

I have modified Ehcache configuration as below，but ehcache data doesn't expire.

```
<cache name="defaultServiceCache"
            maxElementsInMemory="10000" 
            eternal="false" 
            overflowToDisk="true"
            timeToIdleSeconds="500"
            timeToLiveSeconds="1000"
            diskPersistent="false"
            diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"/>
```

A few days later, the Old Gen grows in memory beyond 70% and more than 90% and 30000 elements in Old Gen is ehcache elements.Then JVM crash with many FGC. Any idea?

[image: memory infomation by Eclipse Memory Analyzer]

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24822345/ehcache-not-expiring-elements-from-diskstore

Comment: thx ,ehcache data  is not in disk but in memory